# UIButton in table footer view not responding to touches when keyboard shown

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

I am developing an iPhone app which has a shopping cart, and I'm using a UITableView to display the cart. There is a cell for each item, and the `-tableFooterView` is set to a custom view which gives the user a text field to verify their credit card's CVV and a button to complete the checkout process.

When the user taps in the CVV text field, I resize the table view so that the keyboard doesn't cover anything.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)n
{   
    // I'll update this to animate and scroll the view once everything works 
    self.theTableView.frameHeight = self.view.frameHeight - KEYBOARD_HEIGHT_PORTRAIT_IPHONE;
}
```

After entering their CVV, the user can tap the Done key to dismiss the keyboard:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

All of that works, however, while the keyboard is visible, my checkout button (a normal UIButton) does not respond to touch events. The table scrolls, but the button's touchUpInside event is never fired.

Once I tap Done and the keyboard is dismissed, the checkout button will recognize touchUpInside events.

From what I've seen, it appears that any button that was covered by the keyboard does not respond to my touches (even it scrolled out from behind the keyboard) until the keyboard is dismissed. Buttons in this same -tableFooterView that are not ever covered by the keyboard remain responsive to touch while the keyboard is visible.

Same behavior when running on iOS 5 and iOS 4.

Can anyone offer any suggestions of what may be going on? Or any helpful ideas for troubleshooting?

Thanks!

**Edit - Update**

In fact, the portion of the tableFooterView that is covered by the keyboard is not responding to touch events. In my custom UIView subclass, I implemented `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` and just log that a touch occurred.

Touching anywhere in the view gets a log statement before the keyboard is shown. However, after the tableview is resized, only touching the upper portion of the view generates a log statement.

Also I just realized, the portion of the tableFooterView that was covered by the keyboard turns to the color of the containing view's background color once I scroll that portion to be visible.

Comment: have u found some fix for this?

Comment: @rishi did you find a fix maybe? :)

Comment: @vburojevic yes, but the solution was a bit weird :), I will post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I think it is a bug in iOS, but I've discovered a workaround for it:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [note userInfo];

    // get the size of the keyboard
    NSValue *boundsValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [boundsValue CGRectValue].size; // screen size
    CGFloat keyboardHeight;
    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
        self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height;
    } else {
        keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.width;
    }

    // resize the view with the keyboard
    __block CGRect origFrame = self.view.frame;
    __block CGRect viewFrame = origFrame;
    viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardHeight - ((self.tabBarController != nil) ? self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height : 0);
    // Set the height to zero solves the footer view touch events disabled bug
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(origFrame.origin.x, origFrame.origin.y,
                                 viewFrame.size.width, 0);
    // We immediately set the height back in the next cycle, before the animation starts
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        self.view.frame = origFrame; // The original height
        // start the animation
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
            [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
        }];
    });
}
```

The trick is to set the height of the tableView to 0 and back to original in the next running cycle.

This works for me either iOS 4.3 and 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think that resizing the `UITableView` causes it to send the `UIButton` (a subview) to the back of the view hierarchy. You may need to bring it to the front explicitly after resizing the frame.

```
[self.theTableView bringSubviewToFront:yourUIButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me.

Had a table view footer with button, for that button action is linked via xib, apart from that added following code more -

```
@IBOutlet private weak var myButton: CustomUIButton!

override public func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let myButtonTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myButtonAction(_:)))
    myButton.addGestureRecognizer(myButtonTapGesture)
}

@IBAction func myButtonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    // button action implementation
}
```

So I have to add a tap gesture on button.